# R: From Long format table to "diagonal" format

Tags: r, format

Imagine I have data on long format like this:

```
ID   T     X      Y     Z
1    1     x1    y1    z1
1    2     x2    y2    z2
1    3     x3    y3    z3
2    1     ....
```

With several input variables (here only X and Y) and output variables (here Z).
I've only showed the first rows, belonging to and individual 1, but we would have more data below this.

How can I transform it to this format:

```
1    1     x1                y1                   z1
1    2     x1    x2          y1    y2             z2
1    3     x1    x2    x3    y1    y2    y3       z3 
2    1     ...             ....
```

Where the missing space would be NAs o 0.
Any solution with data.table, dplyr or base R is welcome.

The reason I do it is because I want to a regression like this:

```
y1 = a10 + a11·X1
y2 = a20 + a21·X1 + a22·X2
y3 = a30 + a31·X1 + a32·X2 + a33·X3
```

If you want a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
ID <- rep(1:4,each=4)
XX <- round(runif(16),3)
YY <- round(runif(16),3)
TT <- rep(1:4, 4)
ZZ <- ave(XX*TT,ID, FUN = cumsum)
data.frame(ID,TT,XX, YY, ZZ)

   ID TT    XX    YY    ZZ
1   1  1 0.266 0.718 0.266
2   1  2 0.372 0.992 1.010
3   1  3 0.573 0.380 2.729
4   1  4 0.908 0.777 6.361
5   2  1 0.202 0.935 0.202
6   2  2 0.898 0.212 1.998
7   2  3 0.945 0.652 4.833
8   2  4 0.661 0.126 7.477
9   3  1 0.629 0.267 0.629
10  3  2 0.062 0.386 0.753
11  3  3 0.206 0.013 1.371
12  3  4 0.177 0.382 2.079
13  4  1 0.687 0.870 0.687
14  4  2 0.384 0.340 1.455
15  4  3 0.770 0.482 3.765
16  4  4 0.498 0.600 5.757
```

What if I wanted the result as?

```
1    1     x1                y1                   z1
1    2     x2    x1          y2    y1             z2
1    3     x3    x2    x1    y3    y2    y1       z3 
2    1     ...             ....
```

Comment: I think it can be done with base R from the wide format by replicating every row and later shifting every column a different number...

Comment: Regarding the last edit: That's simple with data.table::shift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roland's answer is good.  You could also use `dcast` and `cumsum`.

It sounds complicated, but it's actually simpler in that it does not require multiple invocations of the triangle function, so it's easier to scale to an arbitrary number of input variables.:

```
df <- data.frame(ID, TT, XX, YY, ZZ)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

input_vars <- c("XX","YY")

dt2 <- dcast(df, ID + TT + ZZ ~ TT, value.var=input_vars, fill=0)
head(dt2)
#    ID TT    ZZ  XX_1  XX_2  XX_3  XX_4  YY_1  YY_2 YY_3  YY_4
# 1:  1  1 0.266 0.266 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.718 0.000 0.00 0.000
# 2:  1  2 1.010 0.000 0.372 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.992 0.00 0.000
# 3:  1  3 2.729 0.000 0.000 0.573 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.38 0.000
# 4:  1  4 6.361 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.908 0.000 0.000 0.00 0.777
# 5:  2  1 0.202 0.202 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.935 0.000 0.00 0.000
# 6:  2  2 1.998 0.000 0.898 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.212 0.00 0.000

# now we just need to get rid of the trailing 0's
# This can be done with a cumulative sum with a keyby ID
cum_cols <- setdiff(names(dt2), c("ID","TT","ZZ"))

dt2[, (cum_cols) := lapply(.SD, cumsum), 
    .SDcols = cum_cols, keyby = ID]

head(dt2)
# looks like:
#    ID TT    ZZ  XX_1  XX_2  XX_3  XX_4  YY_1  YY_2 YY_3  YY_4
# 1:  1  1 0.266 0.266 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.718 0.000 0.00 0.000
# 2:  1  2 1.010 0.266 0.372 0.000 0.000 0.718 0.992 0.00 0.000
# 3:  1  3 2.729 0.266 0.372 0.573 0.000 0.718 0.992 0.38 0.000
# 4:  1  4 6.361 0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908 0.718 0.992 0.38 0.777
# 5:  2  1 0.202 0.202 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.935 0.000 0.00 0.000
# 6:  2  2 1.998 0.202 0.898 0.000 0.000 0.935 0.212 0.00 0.000
```

Comment: Nice. What if the result I wanted were as I added on my post?.  I think this is achieved modifying the last line in your code (reversing something) but it's the most difficult one.

Comment: @skan how badly do you need the result to be a `data.frame`?  It seems like a generic list would be the more logical choice for what you're trying to do, since the column indices are no longer meaningful

Comment: Later I will use it to fit a regression line with repeated measures. Maybe my way is not OK.  I want that ZZ for T=1 only depends on XX1,  that ZZ for T=2 only depends on XX1 and XX2,  and so on.  I mean ZZ at a given time depends on XX at that time and previous XX.

Comment: @skan if you are just trying to rearrange the columns, see `?setcolorder`.  This does not quite line up with your edit (since the x2's will still be in the same column, etc.) but it's not clear to me why you would want a data.frame with a given measure being in different columns on different rows.

Answer (score 3):

Create a function that creates a matrix filled row-wise with the values and sets the upper triangle to zero:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  m <- matrix(x, length(x), length(x), byrow = TRUE)
  m[upper.tri(m)] <- 0
  as.data.frame(m)
}

#test it
fun(1:4)
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  1  0  0  0
#2  1  2  0  0
#3  1  2  3  0
#4  1  2  3  4

library(data.table) #for its by
setDT(DF)
DF[, paste0("x", 1:4) := fun(XX), by = ID]
DF[, paste0("y", 1:4) := fun(YY), by = ID]
#    ID TT    XX    YY    ZZ    x1    x2    x3    x4    y1    y2    y3    y4
# 1:  1  1 0.266 0.718 0.266 0.266 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.718 0.000 0.000 0.000
# 2:  1  2 0.372 0.992 1.010 0.266 0.372 0.000 0.000 0.718 0.992 0.000 0.000
# 3:  1  3 0.573 0.380 2.729 0.266 0.372 0.573 0.000 0.718 0.992 0.380 0.000
# 4:  1  4 0.908 0.777 6.361 0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908 0.718 0.992 0.380 0.777
# 5:  2  1 0.202 0.935 0.202 0.202 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.935 0.000 0.000 0.000
# 6:  2  2 0.898 0.212 1.998 0.202 0.898 0.000 0.000 0.935 0.212 0.000 0.000
# 7:  2  3 0.945 0.652 4.833 0.202 0.898 0.945 0.000 0.935 0.212 0.652 0.000
# 8:  2  4 0.661 0.126 7.477 0.202 0.898 0.945 0.661 0.935 0.212 0.652 0.126
# 9:  3  1 0.629 0.267 0.629 0.629 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.267 0.000 0.000 0.000
#10:  3  2 0.062 0.386 0.753 0.629 0.062 0.000 0.000 0.267 0.386 0.000 0.000
#11:  3  3 0.206 0.013 1.371 0.629 0.062 0.206 0.000 0.267 0.386 0.013 0.000
#12:  3  4 0.177 0.382 2.079 0.629 0.062 0.206 0.177 0.267 0.386 0.013 0.382
#13:  4  1 0.687 0.870 0.687 0.687 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.870 0.000 0.000 0.000
#14:  4  2 0.384 0.340 1.455 0.687 0.384 0.000 0.000 0.870 0.340 0.000 0.000
#15:  4  3 0.770 0.482 3.765 0.687 0.384 0.770 0.000 0.870 0.340 0.482 0.000
#16:  4  4 0.498 0.600 5.757 0.687 0.384 0.770 0.498 0.870 0.340 0.482 0.600
```

For the other result you can use `shift`:

```
DF[, paste0("x", 1:4) := shift(XX, 0:3, fill = 0), by = ID]
#    ID TT    XX    YY    ZZ    x1    x2    x3    x4
# 1:  1  1 0.266 0.718 0.266 0.266 0.000 0.000 0.000
# 2:  1  2 0.372 0.992 1.010 0.372 0.266 0.000 0.000
# 3:  1  3 0.573 0.380 2.729 0.573 0.372 0.266 0.000
# 4:  1  4 0.908 0.777 6.361 0.908 0.573 0.372 0.266
# 5:  2  1 0.202 0.935 0.202 0.202 0.000 0.000 0.000
# 6:  2  2 0.898 0.212 1.998 0.898 0.202 0.000 0.000
# 7:  2  3 0.945 0.652 4.833 0.945 0.898 0.202 0.000
# 8:  2  4 0.661 0.126 7.477 0.661 0.945 0.898 0.202
# 9:  3  1 0.629 0.267 0.629 0.629 0.000 0.000 0.000
#10:  3  2 0.062 0.386 0.753 0.062 0.629 0.000 0.000
#11:  3  3 0.206 0.013 1.371 0.206 0.062 0.629 0.000
#12:  3  4 0.177 0.382 2.079 0.177 0.206 0.062 0.629
#13:  4  1 0.687 0.870 0.687 0.687 0.000 0.000 0.000
#14:  4  2 0.384 0.340 1.455 0.384 0.687 0.000 0.000
#15:  4  3 0.770 0.482 3.765 0.770 0.384 0.687 0.000
#16:  4  4 0.498 0.600 5.757 0.498 0.770 0.384 0.687
```

However, I'm getting the impression that we have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/203914) here. If you explained your actual goal (in a new question, with a reproducible example), better ways could probably suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is interested I've got my own answer for my las question, with base R.

```
ave(df[rep(names(df[3:5]),each=4)], df$ID, FUN=function(x) mapply(
 function(y,z) c(rep(0,z),head(y,length(y)-z)),x,rep(0:3,3)))
```

Comment: There is no `shift` function in base R. (And this is very inefficient.)

Comment: OK, it worked because I had other libraries loaded.
Now it's completly independent from them.